# Accessing data on Amazon's DynamoDB via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

1) Client Access: Is there anyway to perform CRUD operations on DynamoDB using client side JavaScript (REST/Ajax/jQuery)?

I know Amazon has support for .NET and Java.

2) Server Access: Is there any way we can access DynamoDB using server side JavaScript (Node.js) without having to install Java/.NET on the server?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update 2012-12-05**

There is now an official [AWS SDK for Node.js](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornodejs/), see the introductory post [AWS SDK for Node.js - Now Available in Preview Form](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/12/aws-sdk-for-nodejs-now-available-in-preview-form.html) for details, here are the initially supported services:

> The SDK supports [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), **[Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/)**, and the
>   [Amazon Simple Workflow Service](http://aws.amazon.com/swf/), with support for additional services
>   on the drawing board. *[emphasis mine]*

---

**Update 2012-02-27**

[Wantworthy](https://github.com/Wantworthy) has implemented a [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) module for accessing [Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) a week after its launch date, thus covering 2) as well, see [dynode](https://github.com/Wantworthy/dynode):

> Dynode is designed to be a simple and easy way to work with Amazon's
>   DynamoDB service. Amazon's http api is complicated and non obvious how
>   to interact with it. This client aims to offer a simplified more
>   obvious way of working with DynamoDB, but without getting in your way
>   or limiting what you can do with DynamoDB.

---

**Update 2012-02-11**

[Peng Xie](https://github.com/xiepeng) has implemented a [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) module for accessing [Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) at its launch date basically, thus covering 2) already, see [dynamoDB](https://github.com/xiepeng/dynamoDB):

> DynamoDB uses JSON for communication. [...] This module wraps up the request
>   and takes care of authentication. The user will be responsible for
>   crafting the request and consuming the result.

---

Unfortunately there is no official/complete JavaScript SDK for AWS as of today (see [AWS Software Development Kits](http://aws.amazon.com/code) and [boto [Python]](http://code.google.com/p/boto/) for the available offerings).

Fortunately decent coverage for several AWS services in JavaScript is provided by the Node.js library [aws-lib](http://livelycode.com/aws-lib/) already though, which would be a good starting point for adding DynamoDB accordingly. An as of today unresolved feature request to [Add support for DynamoDB](https://github.com/livelycode/aws-lib/issues/36) has been filed already as well.

Further, AWS forum user *gmlvsk3* has recently implemented dedicated [JavaScript interface for DynamoDB](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=85588), but supposedly you *need [a] Java runtime to run it*, because it is based on the [Mozilla Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) JavaScript engine - I haven't reviewed the code in detail yet (at first sight it looks a bit immature though in comparison to e.g. *aws-lib*, but may cover your needs regardless of course), so you should check it out yourself.

Finally, you can implement JavaScript [HTTP Requests to Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/UsingJSON.html) yourself of course (see the [API Reference for Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API.html) for details):

> If you don't use one of the AWS SDKs, you can perform Amazon DynamoDB
>   operations over HTTP using the POST request method. The POST method
>   requires you to specify the operation in the header of the request and
>   provide the data for the operation in JSON format in the body of the
>   request.

Answer (score 1):

I created a module called [Dino](https://github.com/christophercliff/dino) to make it easier to work with the AWS SDK in web applications. You can use something like [Restify](http://mcavage.github.io/node-restify/) to expose your data to jQuery via a REST interface.

Suppose you wanted to display pages of blog posts for a user. Using Dino and Restify, you would do the following:

```
server.get('/posts/:user_id', function(req, res, next){
    Post.find({
        match: {
            user_id: req.params.user_id
        },
        skip: req.params.skip || 0,
        take: req.params.take || 10
    }, function(err, posts){
        return res.send(posts.toJSON());
    });
});
```

Comment: Are skip/take properly pagination? How this implemented? Fullscan?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1), there is now the [AWS SDK for JavaScript in the Browser](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforbrowser/) that allows you to access services including [DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html).

Answer (score 0):

as for 2) we've been working as well since DDB launch date. One of its key features are simplicity/performance and how close it is (retry behavior, etc) to Amazon official Java/PHP libraries:

https://github.com/teleportd/node-dynamodb

It's successfully used in production at various places with 100+ write/s (at teleportd). Additionally we're working on a a mocked version to enable efficient testing of the library's client code.